# How to install a Logitech webcam?

Tags: installation, hardware, drivers, webcam

I'm having problems with installing a webcam:

```
Archive:  /media/LWS_2_0/Setup.exe
[/media/LWS_2_0/Setup.exe]
  End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
zipinfo:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of /media/LWS_2_0/Setup.exe or
          /media/LWS_2_0/Setup.exe.zip, and cannot find /media/LWS_2_0/Setup.exe.ZIP, period.
```

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 18):

Are you trying to install the webcam on Ubuntu?

Have you tried plugging it in and just trying to use it?

Ubuntu contains *lots* of drivers out of the box. For most hardware you don't need to get things from the manufacturer's disks or website.

Try using an application like cheese to see if the camera works.

Comment: My Logitech webcam did not work without `guvcview` installed but worked after I installed the package.

Comment: For me it worked in SD only just plugging it. HD worked after having installed `guvcview` as suggested by @Raphael

Answer (score 13):

To find out the device ID of your webcam, typing `lsusb` in a terminal window will list all USB devices on your system. Try to find the relevant line for your webcam. The ID then appears after "ID" on that line, in the form xxxx:xxxx where the 'x's are numbers or letters

[Logitech webcams](http://www.quickcamteam.net/devices)

In this section you can find various lists related to Logitech webcam devices that will help you identify particular models and what features they support. The lists are divided into UVC and non-UVC webcams. Most of our newer webcams are UVC compatible, so that section is the best one to get started.

[Skype and Web Cameras](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SkypeWebCams)

Following the recent release of a beta version of Skype that has support for video calling, this page will give a list of webcams that have been tested on Skype, and other details. This may differ from the list of webcams working in general on Ubuntu, given here.

Comment: this should bethe accepted answer

Comment: The first link is now broken.

Answer (score 7):

Your Logitech web cam should work out of the box. Try using a program like "guvcview" or "cheese" to check if it's working. setup.exe is made for windows only and windows drivers will not work under Ubuntu or any other non Windows operating system. 
If programs like guvcview  or cheese don't show you the picture, please check if the device if detected, write:

```
ls /dev/video*
```

Now the video devices should be listed. If there are any, you'll need to find the drivers if they exist.

```
lsusb
```

you should see Logitech device listed.

Comment: My Logitech webcam did not work without `guvcview` installed but worked after I installed the package.

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04: I really do not understand what `guvcview` wants to tell me (looks very broken if you ask me).  But - may thanks! - `cheese` works out of the box and full-hd with my c922!  Sadly this does not help me with Chrome, as this still only detects 640x480.

Comment: I just see `/dev/video0` and `/dev/video1`. If I unplug the webcam they both disappear https://askubuntu.com/a/1229301/849369

Answer (score 0):

Just an add "trick" for those who have problems using a logitech webcam on Ubuntu.

If your skype is not seeing your webcam, just start skype with the following command line:

```
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/libv4l/v4l1compat.so /usr/bin/skype
```

If you don't feel like using the console all the time just for skype, try to create a file for it:

```
#!/bin/bash
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/libv4l/v4l1compat.so /usr/bin/skype
```

I used a Logitech for ages, and this commend always helped me :-)

Answer (score -5):

It should detect your webcam under /dev/video0 ?

The error you entered above is because you clicked on the .EXE, but under Ubuntu you need to start an .EXE with Wine

Example

```
wine /media/LWS_2_0/Setup.exe
```

Regards,

Ilias el Matani

Comment: Please, **DO NOT** attempt this with a driver installer. It will not get you anywhere. wine is for running Windows applications, see http://www.winehq.org/about/