# Recognising an internal Logitech camera

Tags: webcam, camera, logitech

I have an Acer Aspire from 2007, it had vista and now has 12.4. My internal camera has never worked and would like to know how to activate it.

Cheese doesn't pick it up.

```
Laptop:~$ lspci -nn
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Mobile 945GM/PM/GMS, 943/940GML and 945GT Express Memory Controller Hub [8086:27a0] (rev 03)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Mobile 945GM/GMS, 943/940GML Express Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:27a2] (rev 03)
00:02.1 Display controller [0380]: Intel Corporation Mobile 945GM/GMS/GME, 943/940GML Express Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:27a6] (rev 03)
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family High Definition Audio Controller [8086:27d8] (rev 02)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family PCI Express Port 1 [8086:27d0] (rev 02)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family PCI Express Port 2 [8086:27d2] (rev 02)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family PCI Express Port 3 [8086:27d4] (rev 02)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family PCI Express Port 4 [8086:27d6] (rev 02)
00:1d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #1 [8086:27c8] (rev 02)
00:1d.1 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #2 [8086:27c9] (rev 02)
00:1d.2 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #3 [8086:27ca] (rev 02)
00:1d.3 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #4 [8086:27cb] (rev 02)
00:1d.7 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB2 EHCI Controller [8086:27cc] (rev 02)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge [8086:2448] (rev e2)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation 82801GBM (ICH7-M) LPC Interface Bridge [8086:27b9] (rev 02)
00:1f.2 IDE interface [0101]: Intel Corporation 82801GBM/GHM (ICH7-M Family) SATA Controller [IDE mode] [8086:27c4] (rev 02)
00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family SMBus Controller [8086:27da] (rev 02)
05:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Atheros Communications Inc. AR242x / AR542x Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) [168c:001c] (rev 01)
06:01.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4401-B0 100Base-TX [14e4:170c] (rev 02)
06:04.0 CardBus bridge [0607]: ENE Technology Inc CB-712/4 Cardbus Controller [1524:1412] (rev 10)
06:04.1 FLASH memory [0501]: ENE Technology Inc ENE PCI Memory Stick Card Reader Controller [1524:0530] (rev 01)
06:04.2 SD Host controller [0805]: ENE Technology Inc ENE PCI Secure Digital Card Reader Controller [1524:0550] (rev 01)
06:04.3 FLASH memory [0501]: ENE Technology Inc FLASH memory: ENE Technology Inc: [1524:0520] (rev 01)
06:04.4 FLASH memory [0501]: ENE Technology Inc SD/MMC Card Reader Controller [1524:0551] (rev 01)
```

Comment: Could you add the output of `lsusb -v` (in the terminal) into your post?

Comment: its rather long but here it is:

Comment: Ok, so no USB devices are attached or recognized (internal camera must be directly attached to the motherboard then)... Could you post the output of `lspci -nn`? And could you indent the output 4 spaces? That way the newlines are preserved :)

Comment: hi lkjoel, so here is the lspci -nn output

Comment: Weird, I can't seem to find the camera... Do you know the make/model of the cam?

Comment: I have an acer aspire from 2007 (5720Z) and the camera works perfectly fine. Did this error just pop up or ever since you installed ubuntu?

Comment: ever since I installed Ubuntu. Mine is an Acer Aspire 5610Z. If I remember correctly it was a Logitech Bison Camera, didn't pay much attention to all the software related to the camera at the time. Is there any hope?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I found the answer, thanks for all those that helped:

Type

```
ls /dev/video*
```

Now the video devices should be listed.

If there are any, you'll need to find the drivers if they exist.
Then type:

```
lsusb
```

At this point install and open Cheese to check if it works it should out of the box

here's where I found the answer: [How to install a Logitech webcam?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24771/how-to-install-a-logitech-webcam)