# 2 device nodes for 1 camera in ubuntu 19.10

Tags: 19.10, camera

On my

```
# dmidecode 3.2
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 2.7 present.

Handle 0x000E, DMI type 1, 27 bytes
System Information
        Manufacturer: LENOVO
        Product Name: 2350B58
        Version: ThinkPad T430
        Serial Number: PBVVBLH
        UUID: cdcb8a01-5190-11cb-9490-98976e1f3194
        Wake-up Type: Power Switch
        SKU Number: LENOVO_MT_2350
        Family: ThinkPad T430
```

is one builtin camera, but I have two device nodes in /dev.

```
ls -ltrh /dev/video*
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 1 Apr 25 08:23 /dev/video1
crw-rw----+ 1 root video 81, 0 Apr 25 08:23 /dev/video0
```

the quality is low.

```
lsusb | grep camera
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 04f2:b2db Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd Thinkpad T430 camera
```

[udevadmin test](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/SVZkc7kFrB/)

running kernel

```
 uname -r   5.3.0-46-generic
```

My system is an upgrade from ubuntu 19.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really I should learn to search with english keywords.

[here ist the explanation for](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1171192/multiple-dev-video-devices-for-1-camera-causing-issue-with-udev-rules) and 
[here](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=088ead25524583e2200aa99111bea2f66a86545a) the background.